# How to customize a many-to-many inline model in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, many-to-many, django-forms

I'm using the admin interface to view invoices and products. To make things easy, I've set the products as inline to invoices, so I will see the related products in the invoice's form. As you can see I'm using a many-to-many relationship.

In models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name  = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    company  = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

In admin.py:

```
class ProductInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Invoice.products.through

class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [FilteredApartmentInline,]
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

The problem is that django presents the products as a table of drop down menus (one per associated product). Each drop down contains all the products listed. So if I have 5000 products and 300 are associated with a certain invoice, django actually loads 300x5000 product names. Also the table is not aesthetic.

I don't need the products to be updatable via the invoice form. How can I change it so that it'll just display the product's name in the inline table?
Which form should I override, and how?

Comment: In admin.py InvoiceAdmin it must be inlines=[ProductInline]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think is simple, don't use the inline, just use the property [ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal)

Comment: That answers my question completely. But now I have a follow up - this shows the list of product names - what if I need it to be links to the products so I can link from the invoice to the products?

Comment: when you select the products in Invoice and save the object you links both objects

Comment: The link provided is dead

Comment: @VKroz I fixed the link. This was for django 1.2 (current django when the question was ask), now I put the link for django 1.7.

Comment: link is broken which is given in answer